# bert + text and structur data

Tags: text, tabular, bert-language-model

For each instance, I have the text and tabular data. I was wondering if there is any way I can use Bert_classification and combine the result to classify the whole dataset without overfitting. Is there any way to make two different classifications for text and tabular data and combine them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BERT can return a vector, so-called `[CLS]` vector that can be used as an input to any further model. So, the answer is yes: you can process your text with BERT and get the single-vector representation, get whatever representation/features you do for your tabular data, concatenate them and train a classifier on top of them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was wondering if I can use BertForSequenceClassification. Does [cls] make by using the class label? If this is the case it can lead to overfitting. Should I use BertModel instead?

Comment: BertForSequenceClassification is just a linear classifier on top of the CLS vector. If you want to combine BERT with other features, you need to use BertModel to get the vector and do the rest of the classifier with your own code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was wondering if I  should use the pooler_output, or I can get average among the CLS in the last 4 layers of Bert in hidden_states. 
Based on the documentation, pooler_output is usually not a good summary of the semantic content of the input, you’re often better with averaging or pooling the sequence of hidden-states for the whole input sequence.